# Flutter TextFormField display overflow text from start position when unfocused

Tags: flutter

When I enter long text into my TextFormField A and jump to another widget (like another TextFormField) my TextFormField A sustains the cursor position at the end of the long text. I want the text to appear from starting position when I unfocus the widget.

**situation**

email field unfocused

[image]

**what I want**

[image]

I've tried

```
textEditingController.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0);
```

but it takes effect only when I focus the widget again not at the moment I unfocus it (which is what I want).

**UPDATE**:
this is my code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController textEditingController1 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController textEditingController2 = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode focusNode1 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode focusNode2 = FocusNode();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textEditingController1.dispose();
    textEditingController2.dispose();
    focusNode1.dispose();
    focusNode2.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            child: TextField(
              focusNode: focusNode1,
              onEditingComplete: () {
                textEditingController1.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0);
                focusNode1.unfocus();
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode2);
              },
              controller: textEditingController1,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            child: TextField(
              focusNode: focusNode2,
              onEditingComplete: () {
                textEditingController2.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0);
                focusNode2.unfocus();
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode1);
              },
              controller: textEditingController2,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could maybe give the `TextField` a `FocusNode` and add a listener to the focus node that resets the text selection when `hasFocus` is no longer true

Comment: @anqit I've tried that also, but no result `@override  void initState() {  widget.focusNode.addListener(() {if (!widget.focusNode.hasFocus) {  textEditingController.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0);}});super.initState();}`

Comment: it would help if you could provide a complete code sample, preferably something that can run (like a dartpad)

Comment: @anqit I've Provided a code sample

Answer (score 0):

after asking BlackBox AI the following:

> I'm using Flutter to create a desktop app that has 2 TextField widgets
> A and B, sometimes the widgets could have long text that disappears
> beyond their limits, in that case, the beginning of the text is not
> visible, I want the text inside the widgets to be visible from its
> beginning when I jump to another widget (now it is visible from where
> I finished typed, usually the end of text, and the beginning not
> visible)

the answer was to use a `ScrollController` widget with its `AnimateTo` method:

answer sample:

```
final ScrollController _scrollControllerA = ScrollController();
final ScrollController _scrollControllerB = ScrollController();

TextField(
  controller: _textControllerA,
  scrollController: _scrollControllerA,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelText: 'TextField A',
  ),
  maxLines: null,
),

TextField(
  controller: _textControllerB,
  scrollController: _scrollControllerB,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelText: 'TextField B',
  ),
  maxLines: null,
),
```

and inside `onEditingComplete`:

```
// Jump to TextField A and scroll to the beginning of the text
_scrollControllerA.animateTo(0.0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);

// Jump to TextField B and scroll to the beginning of the text
_scrollControllerB.animateTo(0.0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
```

That's solved the problem for me, but if anyone has a better answer or a note please tell me, I would appreciate it (prefer Human Intel).

- BTW ChatGPT (copilot) gave me the same answer.